# MVC 3 - Scaffolding drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I am playing with the Scaffolding that is in Asp.net mvc

I have a property on my view model for countries

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
```

Yet, when I create a view and specify the viewmodel it doesn't scaffold a drop down list as I expected it to. In fact it get completely ignored.

I have compiled the project before doing it

I also tried adding a property like this

```
public int CountryId { get; set; }
```

As this article suggested there is a convention at work

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/

I am using the *Add view* option you have when right clicking in a controller action method

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

In my current project, i faced this problem and couldn't find a quick way to scaffold the Dropdown list of a one-many relation inside one of my Entities.

What I ended up doing was like the following:

1- Create the normal AddView=>Create way.

2- If i had a ID property in my model class, the defaul;t template will generate something like this to represent this property in my view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityID)
</div>
```

3- Now I need to replace this default template with a working one, so I wrote this code in the `CREATE` method:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cityItems = dataContext.Cities.AsEnumerable().Select(c => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = c.Name,
                Value = c.ID.ToString(),
                Selected = false,
            });
            SelectList cityList = new SelectList(cityItems, "Value", "Text");
            ViewBag.CityList = cityList;
```

this will fetch the Cities table and create a Selectlist that i can pass to my view and work with it to provide the DrobDown with it's items.

4- replace the default code in my View by one like the following:

```
<div class="Post-label">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityID)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, ViewData["CityList"] as SelectList)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityID)
                        </div>
</div>
```

The reason I've used `ViewData["CityList"]` instead of `ViewBag.CityList` is that this one worked but the other not.

5- now my view is working find and is fetching the `City` data just like what I expected, and using the same model inside my `Edit` view resulted in a working one too.

Give it a try and let me know what happened, Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I know how to hand code it, I'm just trying to find out why the automatic scaffolding doesn't work for this scenario

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed that for a given model, the "Create" scaffold-generated code when creating a new controller is different than if you right-click in an existing controller and say "Add View" and choose the "Create" scaffolding template.  In the first case, given you have the correct properties on the child class

```
public Country Country {get;set;}
public int CountryID {get;set;}
```

then this case (adding controller with MVC scaffolding read/write and appropriate Model class) WILL generate a @Html.DropDownList for the parent relationship, whereas right-clicking within the controller Create method will not scaffold the drop-down but will instead create an @Html.EditorFor for the relationship.

So the answer if you want scaffolding code to generate the drop-down may be to delete and re-create your controller if possible, otherwise manually add in the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the option to choose a country with a dropdown the property in your Model should be:

`public Country Country{ get; set; }` *Navigation property used by EF, doesn't involve the database*

with

`public Country CountryId{ get; set; }`
 *Create the foreign key on the Person table*

Each instance/record of a person is associated with a country: the relation is defined with the navigation property via code and with the CountryID for the database. 
The scaffholding template will then generate the edit/create methods and views using :

```
ViewBag.PossibleCountries
```

[Here's a similar scenario.](http://george2giga.com/2011/08/05/ef-code-first-with-mvc-3-scaffholding/)